# Snowflake: Can I copy an empty file into a table

Tags: database, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to use a copy into command using an empty file as follows:

```
put file://C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test.csv @~/staged overwrite=TRUE;

copy into test_db.test_schema.test_table
from @~/staged/test.csv.gz;
```

The file C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test.csv is an empty file without any column names. I am expecting that all the data in the test_table will be replaced by nulls. But, it is not. Is there a way to use an empty file to truncate the data in the table test_table and not use the TRUNCATE statement?

Comment: You want all of your data to be replaced with NULL? That's different from truncating the data from the table. If you have 10 rows in the table and 0 in the CSV file, do you want 10 rows with NULLs in every column or 0 rows in the table after the COPY statement? Why not just truncate the table before you run the COPY?

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish here, because using an empty file with a PUT and a COPY is twice as many statements as executing a TRUNCATE statement.  What is it you're trying to do?